# PHP - filesystem lib with command pattern

Tags: php, transactions, filesystems, distributed-transactions

I am looking for a filesystem library which implements the command pattern, so I can undo changes made in the filesystem, and for example by database errors I can protect the data integrity easily in a primitive way (with probably pessimistic locking)...

Do you know about such a system, or do I have to implement it myself?

This example will be a little bit dummy, because we usually would do it with file replacement and we would keep the file name in the database. Please forget about that for a moment...

Example:

```
try {
    $delete = $file1->delete();
    $create = $file2->create();
    $trans = $db->createTransaction(function () use ($db){
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE files SET name = :new_name WHERE name = :old_name');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'old_name' => $file1->name,
            'new_name' => $file2->name
        ));
    });
    $trans->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e){
    if ($trans)
        $trans->rollback();
    if ($create)
        $create->undo();
    if ($delete)
        $delete->undo();
    throw $e;
}
```

Ofc. I want to handle the rollback automatically and check whether the file locking order (if there is a lock) is abc to prevent deadlocks.

For example with an interface something like this:

```
try {
    $commands = new Commands();
    $commands->add(new FileDeleteCommand($file1));
    $commands->add(new FileCreateCommand($file2));
    $commands->add(new DatabaseTransaction(
        function ($db) use ($file1, $file2){
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE files SET name = :new_name WHERE name = :old_name');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                'old_name' => $file1->name,
                'new_name' => $file2->name
            ));
        }
    ));
    $commands->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $commands->undo();
    throw $e;
}
```

There are limitations by this approach, for example I have to commit the transaction in the last place, because I cannot rollback it when it is already committed, but I can live with that...

Or an alternative interface:

```
try {
    $transactions = new DistributedTransaction();

    $transactions->add(new FileSystemTransaction(
        function () use ($file1, $file2){
            $file1->delete();
            $file2->create();
        }
    ));

    $transactions->add(new DatabaseTransaction(
        function ($db) use ($file1, $file2){
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE files SET name = :new_name WHERE name = :old_name');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                'old_name' => $file1->name,
                'new_name' => $file2->name
            ));
        }
    ));
    $transactions->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $transactions->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Ofc the problem is that how do we commit 2 transactions at once? I think the only way that we implement one of them: the filesystem transaction, but I am open for suggestions...

I added a new tag, I think this is a simple [distributed transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) issue with a database transaction resource and a filesystem transaction resource.

Comment: What's wrong with transactional DB?

Comment: Nothing, I just don't want to store files in db. Btw. I like to have options...

Comment: But the thing you are looking for is transactional DB. Or may be you mean VCS? Like git/SVN ?

Comment: Nope. I want to store uploaded files and just their names in the database. In this scenario the data integrity can be damaged for example when the database connection fails and the files are already modified. Pessimistic locking or optimistic locking with temporary multiversioning the files can be solutions, but I don't want to build an entire database, just a simple protection.

Comment: I added an example maybe it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything similar in PHP, so I started my own [php-transactions](https://github.com/inf3rno/php-transactions) project to fill the gap.

It will have implementations of distributed transaction and filesystem transaction with limited functionality. I intend to add some support for cooperative multitasking, with that it will be easier to separate filesystem and database transactions when they depend on each other. It will work with promises, and generators as well. I think I'll finish with the 1.0 until the end of June 2014.